# Explanation of a Jaden Casing Solution

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone provide a detailed explanation of how this function works:

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
  return this.replace(/(^|\s)[a-z]/g, function(x){ return x.toUpperCase(); });
};
```

Also, what are some good resources for understanding regular expressions?

Thanks

Comment: This (https://regular-expressions.mobi/tutorial.html) is a great resource  for learning and is the most in-depth.

Answer (score 1):

The function appears to ensure that all words following a whitespace (`\s`) beginning with a lowercase letter `[a-z]` are raised to uppercase.  The replace function searches for all occurrences of begin-string or whitespace `(^|\s)` followed by any lowercase alpha character `[a-z]`.  It then passes that 'space plus alpha' substring  to a function that raises all alphas to uppercase.  The returned uppercase substring is written into the result string, replacing the matched character(s),  The `/g` after the regex ensures that all matches are processed, not just the first one.